# how to reload a circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made some web searching about canvas and how to create a circular progress bar and i got this. I made some changes to the pieces of code that I found online but i can't reload the circular path again. By reload I mean, when the circle is full ( a perfect circle) I would like to draw it again. In other words, I would like to repeat the procedure of drawing the circle again after a full spin is completed. I tried to clear the whole canvas when my variable trigger is greater than 100, but no success. Any ideas?

here's the code

```js
function draw() {
    var c=document.getElementById("prog");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var time = 0;
    var start = 4.72;
    var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
    var ch = ctx.canvas.height; 
    var diff;

    function justdoit(){
        
        diff = ((time / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
        
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        
        ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        
        ctx.fillText( time+'s', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
        ctx.beginPath();
        
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 30, start, diff/10+start, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        if(trigger >= 100){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        }
        time++;
    }
    var trigger = setInterval(justdoit, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="draw()"> draw </button>
<canvas id="prog"></canvas>
```

The function draw is called on a button element with an attribute onclick="draw()";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are after, I have separated the timer out for the position of the circle so you can reset the position to 0 every 100 seconds without reseting the time.

The important things I have changed:

Added a new variable called `pos`.

```
var pos = 0;
```

Changed the `diff` calculation to use `pos`.

```
diff = ((pos / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
```

Changed the if statement to set `pos` back to 0 every 100 seconds and clear the circle.

```
if(time % 100 == 0){
    pos = 0;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
}
```

Increment `pos` with `time`.

```
pos++;
```

*Also I have decreased the timer in the example so we don't have to wait a long time to see. - Change back to `1000` for 1 second interval `setInterval(justdoit, 100);`*

```js
function draw() {
    var c=document.getElementById("prog");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var time = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    var start = 4.72;
    var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
    var ch = ctx.canvas.height; 
    var diff;

    function justdoit(){
        
        diff = ((pos / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
        
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        
        ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        
        ctx.fillText( time+'s', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
        ctx.beginPath();
        
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 30, start, diff/10+start, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        if(time % 100 == 0){
            pos = 0;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        }
        time++;
        pos++;
    }
    var trigger = setInterval(justdoit, 100);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="draw()"> draw </button>
<canvas id="prog"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're one step ahead of me! That's exactly want i needed, keeping the time var unaltered. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The last 'if' block is wrong. Use this instead:

```
if(time >= 100){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    time = 0;
}
```

This will just make the thing repeat itself over and over again. Hopefully this was what you wanted.

The complete code is here (I speeded the thing up by changing the step wait time from '1000' to '10 in the second line from the bottom):

```js
function draw() {
    var c=document.getElementById("prog");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var time = 0;
    var start = 4.72;
    var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
    var ch = ctx.canvas.height; 
    var diff;

    function justdoit(){
        
        diff = ((time / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
        
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        
        ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        
        ctx.fillText( time+'s', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
        ctx.beginPath();
        
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 30, start, diff/10+start, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        if(time >= 100){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
            time = 0;
        }
        time++;
    }
    var trigger = setInterval(justdoit, 10);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="draw()"> draw </button>
<canvas id="prog"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah got it, the only thing I need to do now is keep the time var. Thanks :)